# Music LaTex a two-hand piece of music (C-major K545 by Mozart)

Tags: music, musixtex

I have the following code and it supposes to output the following music  (C-major K545 by Mozart)

[image]

But I am unable to make it work, can someone see what is the problem for my package and document setup

```
\documentclass[11pt,urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue]{article} 


\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{wasysym}





\begin{document}


\begin{music}
\parindent 1cm
\def\nbinstruments{1}\relax % a single instrument
\def\instrumenti{Piano}%    % whose name is Piano
\nbporteesi=2\relax         % with two staffs
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}}\relax % 4/4 meter chosen
\debutextrait               % starting real score
\normal                     % normal 12 pt note spacing
\temps\Notes\ibu0f0\qh0{cge}\tbu0\qh0g|\hl j\enotes
\temps\Notes\ibu0f0\qh0{cge}\tbu0\qh0g|\ql l\sk\ql n\enotes
\barre                      % bar
\Notes\ibu0f0\qh0{dgf}|\qlp i\enotes
\notes\tbu0\qh0g|\ibbl1j3\qb1j\tbl1\qb1k\enotes
\temps\Notes\ibu0f0\qh0{cge}\tbu0\qh0g|\hl j\enotes
\finextrait                 % terminate excerpt
\end{music}



\end{document}
```

for other info, please see [this](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/musictex/musicdoc.pdf).

I am using the document class [article].

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to typeset a complete score (and not just a part which is included in the text of a bigger document) then I strongly recommend using something like [musescore](https://musescore.com/). LaTeX is great but music scores are not on its strong side…

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't confuse [MusicTeX](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/musictex) with [MusiXTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/musixtex). The example loads `musixtex`, then code for the music becomes ([documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/musixtex/doc/musixdoc.pdf), "1.2 A simple example"):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\instrumentnumber{1}        % a single instrument
\setname1{Piano}            % whose name is Piano 
\setstaffs1{2}              % with two staffs
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}} % 4/4 meter chosen
\startextract               % starting real score
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\hl j\en
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\ql l\sk\ql n\en
\bar                        % bar
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{dgf}|\qlp i\en
\notes\tbu0\qb0g|\ibbl1j3\qb1j\tbl1\qb1k\en
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\hl j\en
\zendextract                % terminate excerpt
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

MusicTeX is older and seems no longer maintainted. TeX Live does not include it and needs to be installed first. Therefore, I would prefer MusiXTeX. Also, I recommend to take a look at [LilyPond](http://lilypond.org/).