# How to change \footnote notation locally to music symbols/notes?

Tags: symbols, numbering, footnotes, music

I learned earlier [How to change \footnote notation locally in a few places?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470600/41144), how to change footnotes to certain symbols: like

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\newcommand{\symfootnote}[1]{%
\let\oldthefootnote=\thefootnote%
\stepcounter{mpfootnote}%
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}%
\footnote{#1}%
\let\thefootnote=\oldthefootnote%
}
```

However, this is not enough for my purpose. I hope to use some music symbols or the following symbols locally as footnotes. [See this](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf)

[image]

How do I do this? Actually there are just three places I need them, in the front page, where I insert the 4 Authors Email information. Which I need, say
the

> G clef (Treble clef), F clef (Bass clef), Sharp Sign, Flat Sign

as my quoted and footnote symbols.

See also [Music LaTex a two-hand piece of music (C-major K545 by Mozart)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375373/41144)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `lilyglyphs` package (requires XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) for the symbols, and the `footmisc` package to define a footnote symbol set.

```
% compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[perpage,symbol*]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\DefineFNsymbols*{music}{\clefGInline\clefFInline\sharp\flat}
\setfnsymbol{music}
\begin{document}
Some text.\footnote{First footnote} Some more text\footnote{Second footnote} Some more text\footnote{Third footnote} Some more text\footnote{Fourth footnote}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

If you have a font that contains the clefs (most fonts contain the accidentals) then you can use that font to supply the characters without using `lilyglyphs`. Since you may not want to use that font as the main document font in the following example I've created a font family using Free Serif specifically for the musical symbols. To my eye the scaling of the symbols isn't very good compared to the `lilyglyphs` version, however.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\musicfont{Free Serif}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmusic}{\musicfont}
\newcommand*\clefG{\textmusic{\char"1D122}}
\newcommand*\clefF{\textmusic{\char"1D11E}}
\usepackage[perpage,symbol*]{footmisc}
\DefineFNsymbols*{music}{\clefG\clefF{\textmusic{\sharp}}{\textmusic{\flat}}}
\setfnsymbol{music}
\begin{document}
Some text.\footnote{First footnote} Some more text\footnote{Second footnote} Some more text\footnote{Third footnote} Some more text\footnote{Fourth footnote}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don’t even need `lilyglyphs` if you’re using `fontspec` anyway; these symbols are in Unicode: ♮ ♯ ♭     ♩ ♪, etc.

Comment: I have many fonts, and only one (Apple Symbol) has clefs in it.

Comment: You don’t need to, but you can select that font. That said, several fonts that ship with TeX Live support it also, including Free Serif and Code 2000.

Comment: @Davislor  Yes of course I could select that font, but selecting an Apple proprietary font didn't seem as helpful as the `lilyglyphs` solution. Since Free Serif contains clefs too, I'll show that way to do things too.

Comment: thanks +1, Can it be compiled by LaTeX ?

Comment: I ask a different question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471861/ restricted to Latex

Comment: @wonderich I'm not sure this really warrants a separate question. If you can find a Type1 font or package that supplies the clef symbols, then the method is identical. I couldn't find such a font or package, so I went with a Unicode solution.

Comment: You say the scaling in the second example looks poor. Did you intend to scale the font family with `[Scale = MatchUppercase]`.? That seems to have been omitted.