# In PDFTeX, how do I change \footnote notation locally to music symbols/notes?

Tags: macros, symbols, numbering, footnotes, music

This is related to a previous question [How to change \footnote notation locally to music symbols/notes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471772/41144).

> I am hoping to change, the \symfootnote * and \dagger define below to
>
> 1. the \sharp and \flat music symbols.

or

> 2. the G clef (Treble clef) and F clef (Bass clef) symbols.

While other parts of enumerations are perfectly fine to me.

> If you can do 1, it is a perfectly good answer for me.
>
> If you can do 2, it is a bonus to me but it is not necessary.

How do I do that within PDFLaTeX (without using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) as @Alan Munn did in [How to change \footnote notation locally to music symbols/notes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471772/41144)

[image]

Here is my failed attempt so far:

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\symfootnote}[1]{%
\let\oldthefootnote=\thefootnote%
\stepcounter{mpfootnote}%
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{\sharp\flat}}%
\footnote{#1}%
\let\thefootnote=\oldthefootnote%
}

\begin{document}

This document\footnote{first letter} may have 
several\footnote{second letter} 
footnotes\symfootnote{first symbol}. 

While most of them\footnote{third letter} are 
alphabetical\footnote{fourth letter}, some are 
symbolic\symfootnote{second symbol} also, to 
preserve variety\footnote{fifth letter}.

\end{document}
```

An outcome like this in *PDFLaTeX* (not using XeLaTeX nor LuaLaTeX) will be an excellent answer too!

[image]

Comment: If you want different footnote series, (called 'apparatus') then you should use the `bigfoot`/`manyfoot` package, and assign the symbol list in roughly the same way. For a LaTeX solution you would need to find a font or package that supplies the clefs. I couldn't find one. I guess you could create a character using images of the clefs if you really needed LaTeX. See e.g. [How to turn a figure into a symbol?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/31490) and [Create a symbol font from SVG symbols](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/22487).

Comment: I’ve slightly edited your question to remove an ambiguity: the `latex` command on some systems is an alias for the PDFTeX engine, but “LaTeX” more often refers to the language itself, compiled on any engine.

Comment: @Davislor, thanks for the info!!!! +1

Comment: Are you able to make the 1st and the 2nd symbols to be "the \sharp and \flat music symbols" respectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically when multiple footnote apparatus are used, one is used on a per page basis, and one is used with a more global numbering system (per chapter or document).  Symbol footnote systems are almost exclusively implemented on a per page basis, since there is usually a very small set of symbols, and so they are inappropriate for document or chapter wide scope.  One fairly standard way to implement this in LaTeX is to use the  `bigfoot` package, This package implements the `manyfoot` package  with some improvements, and you should consult the `manyfoot` documentation for how to use it.

So here's an example of how to do this. The first example uses pdfLaTeX, but lacks the clefs. I have not managed to find either of the clef symbols in any Type1 font. But many fonts contain the accidentals, so they can be implemented easily. By design, `manyfoot` separates the two different footnote series, so you can't have interspersed numeric and symbol footnotes.  The second example simply uses the same method described in my previous answer, but adds the `bigfoot` code for the different numbering systems.

### pdfLaTeX with just sharp and flat symbols

```
% compile with pdfLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bigfoot} % See the manyfoot package for documentation
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}
\DefineFNsymbols*{music}{{$\sharp$}{$\flat$}*{$\dag$}}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\fnsymbol{footnoteA}}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA}
\setfnsymbol{music}
\begin{document}
Some text\footnoteB{A regular footnote.} Some text\footnoteA{A symbol footnote}. Some text\footnoteB{Another regular footnote} Some text\footnoteA{Another symbol footnote} Some text\footnoteA{A symbol footnote} Some text\footnoteA{A symbol footnote}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX with clef symbols added

```
% compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{bigfoot} % See the manyfoot package for documentation
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\musicfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Free Serif}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmusic}{\musicfont}
\newcommand*\clefG{\textmusic{\char"1D122}}
\newcommand*\clefF{\textmusic{\char"1D11E}}

\DeclareNewFootnote{B}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\DefineFNsymbols*{music}{\clefG\clefF{\textmusic{\sharp}}{\textmusic{\flat}}}
\setfnsymbol{music}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\fnsymbol{footnoteA}}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA}

\begin{document}
Some text\footnoteB{A regular footnote.} Some text\footnoteA{A symbol footnote}. Some text\footnoteB{Another regular footnote} Some text\footnoteA{Another symbol footnote} Some text\footnoteA{A symbol footnote}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### pdfLaTeX using images for the clefs

If you really need to use pdfLaTeX and require the clef symbols, then you could insert them as graphics. To do this I made images of the clefs using the `standalone` package and LuaLaTeX. Here's the document for the treble clef. This produced a file `clefF.pdf`.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Free Serif}
\newcommand*\clefG{\char"1D122}
\newcommand*\clefF{\char"1D11E}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont
\clefF
\end{document}
```

For the bass clef, I used the same procedure, but I also used the `pdfcrop` script to crop the resulting image, since the default crop used by `standalone` didn't seem to crop completely.  So after I created `clefG.pdf` I used the command `pdfcrop clefG.pdf`. This produced `clefG-crop.pdf` which I renamed back to be `clefG.pdf`.  Now we can define commands to insert the clef images as symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareRobustCommand\clefG{\includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{clefG}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\clefF{\includegraphics[height=2ex]{clefF}}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}
\DefineFNsymbols*{music}{{\clefG}{\clefF}{$\sharp$}{$\flat$}}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\fnsymbol{footnoteA}}
\setfnsymbol{music}
\begin{document}
Some text\footnoteB{A regular footnote.} Some text\footnoteA{A symbol footnote}. Some text\footnoteB{Another regular footnote} Some text\footnoteA{Another symbol footnote} Some text\footnoteA{A symbol footnote} Some text\footnoteA{A symbol footnote}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: thanks +1, excellent!!!

Comment: Good lessons for all of us.

Comment: Dear Alan, I like to accept your answer, but could you help me on one thing:

Comment: If I just wish to minimally modify my code, could I do something like (similar to yours):

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbols{{$\sharp$}{$\flat$}*{$\dag$}}}

Comment: but which gives the same effect as your first part of answer? (This is just modifying one line in my code -- but for unknown reason, it cannot work)

Comment: Modifying mine to 
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbols{{$\sharp$}{$\flat$}*{$\dag$}}}
cannot be compiled?

Comment: `\fnsymbols` provides a list of the symbols that will be used in the `\fnsymbol` command. It is not the `\fnsymbol` command itself.

Comment: Thanks! --- but I am flat not sure I fully follow how to modify....

Comment: I also find \clefG{\char"1D122} \clefF{\char"1D11E} \clefC{\char"1D121}

Comment: What you're trying to do really doesn't make sense to do. Mixing symbols and numbers using the regular fn counter will always run you into difficulties, because you'll quickly run out of symbols. So it really only makes sense if you have separate counters, which is what the solution I gave does.